# M2: How to detect Customer Account Age

Tags: magento2, customer-account

How to detect customer account years old?

**example:**

Customer Account has created at **2018-05-17 15:20:35**,I want to add text "**Anniversary**" if the account has been 1 year.

Comment: where do you want to add this text ?

Comment: I want to add the text in customer account info.

Comment: if you can please share a snaphot of Customer Accout section , where and in which place you want to show Anniversary and Do it will be placed all the time for all the customers who completed there 1 year or 2 Year or nth year ? basically , what we have to do , make a separate custom module which can override files of customer account of that section where you want to put your content.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can get do it by finding customer Created at and present data.
You just need to load customer and get its **Created_at** value and today's date and get the difference of dates.

If you find this answer useful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for it

```
$customerID = 2; // your customer-id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
            ->load($customerID);

$birthDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($customerObj->getCreatedAt()));

$time = strtotime($birthDate);
if(date('m-d') == date('m-d', $time)) {
    echo "Today is Birthday";
}else{
    echo "Not Birthday today";
}
?>
```